# How to set up TFS 2010 in Visual Studio 2010 Premium/Ultimate?

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2010, tfs

This might sound like a silly question but is there a manual or a guide on how to set up Team Foundation Server 2010 in Visual Studio 2010 Premium or Ultimate? It comes built-in right?

I've only got up to the Server list part. It's asking me to select a TFS server and port, but I don't think I have one. All I have installed is Visual Studio 2010. According to this [product comparison](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products) page, TFS 2010 should come pre-installed with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Team Foundation Server is the source control server application.  It is not the same as Visual Studio 2010 Premium/Ultimate.

In order to use TFS, you must install it on a machine on your network, then connect to it using the **client**, which is what comes preinstalled with Visual Studio.

Back in 2008, you'd have to download the TFS Client separately and install that in order to connect Visual Studio to a TFS instance.  This might be what's leading to your confusion.

Comment: I see. I was mainly confused about Server and Client TFS. But it's clear now.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't come built in.  Team Foundation Server is a separate product from Visual Studio; the (slightly misleading) table on the page you linked does indicate that TFS "can be purchased separately."